# SharePoint workflow emails stopped showing the site name at the "sent From" field

Tags: sharepoint

all the sudden, all the SharePoint 2013 workflow emails notifications are coming through as SharePoint Online no-reply@sharepointonline.com which is creating a significant confusion and frustration within users that now cannot identify the site origin of the notification

Has anybody experienced the same issue, and have identified any potential workaround to make the "site name" to appear back in the notifications?

Comment: hmm, I found this https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/changing-from-address-on-workflow-email/41ed3374-da38-46c2-89d3-5f7fa0f613a1
I believe that you are stuck in a pretty weird situation, where these workflows are getting deprecated just like the software that created those workflows. I think you best bet would be to turn those workflows to Power Automate Workflows and set up the office365 connectors with shared emails.